# Find all sub-graphes containing at least one node having a certain property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My graph is composed of multiple "sub-graphes" that are disconnected from one another. These sub-graphes are composed of nodes that are connected with a given relation type.

I would like to get (for example) the list of sub-graphes that contain at least one node that has the property "name" equals "John".

It's equivalent to finding one node per subgraph having this property.

One solution would be to find all the nodes having this property and loop through this list to only pick the ones that are not connected to the previously picked ones. But that would be ugly and quite heavy. Is there an elegant way to do that with Cypher?

I'm trying with something along this direction but have no success so far:

> START source=node:user('name:"John"')
>   MATCH source-[r?:KNOWS*]-target
>   WHERE r is null
>   RETURN source

Comment: When you say find the subgraphs, what are you expecting to be returned? And in the query above, why do you have the clause WHERE r is null?

Comment: I'd like to get a list of nodes that are not connected with each other (to any degree of separation) and have this common property. They can be connected with other nodes though. But I would like only one of these nodes per subset. Let's say there are three nodes having this property (A, B and C). A and B are connected with each other but C is not connected to any. I would like the query to return either A and C or B and C.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it may help

```
START source=node:user('name:"John"')
MATCH source-[r:KNOWS]-()-[r2:KNOWS]-target
WHERE NOT(source-[r:KNOWS]-target)
RETURN target
```